# Read lines containing integers from a file in Python?

Tags: python, file-io, casting

I have a file format like this:

```
9 8 1
3 4 1
...
...
```

Now, I want to get each line as three integers.

When I used

```
for line in f.readlines():
    print line.split(" ")
```

The script printed this:

```
['9', '8', '1\r\n']
['3', '4', '1\r\n']
...
...
```

How can I get each line as three integers?

Comment: Do you mean `for line in f.readlines():`

Comment: Don't cast. Convert. The more general question for that is: "How to covert '123' to the corresponding number 123?"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using the code you have and addressing your specific question of how to convert your list to integers:

You can iterate through each line and convert the strings to `int` with the following example using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

Given:

```
line =['3', '4', '1\r\n']
```

then:

```
int_list = [int(i) for i in line]
```

will yield a list of integers

```
[3, 4, 1]
```

that you can then access via subscripts (0 to 2). e.g.

`int_list[0]` contains `3`,

`int_list[1]` contains `4`,

etc.

---

A more streamlined version for your consideration:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        int_list = [int(i) for i in line.split()]
        print int_list
```

The advantage of using `with` is that it will automatically close your file for you when you are done, or if you encounter an exception.

**UPDATE**:

Based on your comments below, if you want the numbers in 3 different variables, say `a`, `b` and `c`, you can do the following:

```
   for line in f:
       a, b, c = [int(i) for i in line.split()]
       print 'a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n' %(a, b, c)
```

and get this:

```
    a = 9, b = 8, c = 1
```

This counts on there being 3 numbers on each line.

*Aside:*

Note that in place of "list comprehension" (LC) you can also use a "generator expression" (GE) of this form:

```
    a, b, c = (int(i) for i in line.split())
```

for your particular problem with 3 integers this doesn't make much difference, but I show it for completeness.  For larger problems, LC requires more memory as it generates a complete list in memory at once, while GE generate a value one by one as needed. This SO question [Generator Expressions vs. List Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension) will give you more information if you are curious.

Comment: Actually, I haven't enough reputation to vote. Vote up requires at least 15 reputation.                       If I want to use the data to build a graph datastructure, format them as a list is a bad choice. Is there some easy way to format them just as three single integer?

Comment: @sezina you don't need any points to accept an answer. It's the little  check-mark on the side of this answer.

Comment: @Levon: It does't work. I got a `ValurError: need more then 2 values to unpack`.

Comment: @sezina Check your data file, make sure it only contains 3 numbers per line and there are no blank lines (at the end of the file either). I tested this code with a file before I posted it, so it works. This message comes when you *have fewer* than 3 items on a line. In this case you must have only **2** items on a line.

Comment: @Levon: Aha. I solved the problem. Thanks a lot. And I have accepted.

Comment: @sezina Did you have only 2 values on a line? Just curious. Happy to help.

Answer (score 4):

```
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        int_list = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
```

You don't say what you want to do with the list of integers, there may be a better way to iterate over them, depending.

If you "need the values as three different variables," then"

```
a, b, c = int_list
```

though you could also use:

```
int_list[0]
int_list[1]
int_list[2]
```

as desired.

Comment: As a note - the `.strip()` is redundant

Comment: Thanks. If I want to use the data to build a graph datastructure, format them as a list is a bad choice. Is there some easy way to format them just as three single integer?

Comment: @JonClements: true enough, I removed it.

Comment: @sezina: we'd need a lot more details to know how to help you build a graph.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: I need get the value as three different variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
line.strip().split(" ")
```

would do.

more complete, with all lines still intact in one large string:

```
data = f.read().strip()    # loose final \n
[ int(x.split(" ")) for x in data.split('\n')]
```

would give you a list with answers you want for each line.

Answer (score 0):

This block of code should solve your problem:

```
f = open(filepath)
for line in f:
    intList = map(int, line.strip().split())
    print intList
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna store the integers in three variables :

```
with open('data1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a,b,c=(int(x) for x in line.split()) 
        print a,b,c
```

**output:**

```
9 8 1
3 4 1
```